# show 3 rows data as single data

Tags: html, sql

Need to display sql data in [SQL Image data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YZq4.png) input

```
public List< LaunchpadLoanStructure> LoanStructureList { get; set; }
```

based on condition we will get 3 rows for ID

HTML code

```
   <form>
        <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
            <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">1st (Permanent) Loan :</label>

            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <input type="text" id="txtfirstamoritization">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <input type="text" id="txtfirstpercentage">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <input type="text" id="txtfirstrate">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
            <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">2nd (Interim) Loan :</label>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <input type="text" id="txtsecondamoritization">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <input type="text" id="txtsecondpercentage">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <input type="text" id="txtsecondrate">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
            <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">SBA 504 Loan :</label>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <input type="text" id="txtSBAamoritization">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <input type="text" id="txtSBArate">
            </div>
        </div>
   </form>
```

Comment: What issue you are facing?

Comment: need how to display the data at html

Comment: Did you try something and getting any exception?

Comment: I have tried value="@(lp.SBAListItemID == 1 ? "" : lp.Amoritization) for input but I am not getting

Comment: Please add all the relevant code to the question and specify the issue you are facing